# AWS SES Upgrade from version 2 to version 4?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We received an email recently from AWS:

---

**Subject:** [Action Required] Important notification regarding Simple Email Service (SIGv2 Deprecation)

**Body:**
We recently observed Signature Version 2 requests on an Amazon SES SMTP endpoint originating from your account. xxxxxxxxxxxxxx etc

---

**Problem:**

- We are not using AWS SES API to send requests, we just use the SmtpClient to send emails. This method does not provide for signing requests.
  Their own example does not include any signing.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-net.html
- In the SES dashboard there is no option for changing the version
- For the current version 2, we have never added any Signature.

**Question:**
So what exactly do I need to upgrade ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**AWS Finally send me a new email with instructions:**

To migrate to Signature Version 4, please replace your existing SMTP credentials using the appropriate procedure relative to your setup:

- If you generated your SMTP credentials using the SES Console, simply create new credentials and replace your existing credentials with the new ones.
- If you derived your SMTP credentials from your AWS credentials, make sure you are using the Signature Version 4 algorithm. If you rely on a library to do this conversion, check if the library has a newer release that uses Signature Version 4 algorithm and migrate to it. Otherwise, you will need to either derive the credentials from another library that uses Signature Version 4 algorithm or generate credentials using the SES console.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SES through hSMTP (i.e. not through the API) you have 2 options:

1. [Obtaining Amazon SES SMTP credentials using the Amazon SES console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html#smtp-credentials-console)
2. [Obtaining Amazon SES SMTP credentials by converting existing AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html#smtp-credentials-convert)

In the second link, there are also code samples in Java and Python.

You can see that the version variable is set to **4** (which indicates signature version 4).

After you have the "new" password - you should put this value as the password value when using the SMTPCLient

Answer (score 1):

I'm also in the same situation. I do not know how to upgrade it to version 4. I read it somewhere that I just need to re create the SMTP credentials. But I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: if you just have to recreate credentials .. then you can follow this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

Comment: I tried this method but now none of the new keys work. They all get authentication errors. Old keys still work doing the same commands.

Comment: I have upgraded the SMTP credentials and the new credentials working fine. But I would like to confirm whether recreating the SMTP credentials is enough to upgrade the signature version to 4.

Comment: @Lu_Bu I've the same problem. I found that we need to switch to the correct region (e.g. `us-east-1`) which matches my SMTP host before generating the SMTP credentials. After that, the newly created credentials works for me.